# Ubuntu 16.0.4 won't recognize phone as media device when connected with usb 3 cable

Tags: usb, phone, media

So when I plug my phone (Samsung galaxy note 3) into my computer using a regular micro sd cable, Ubuntu recognises it as a media device, and all is well.

But when I connect it using the USB 3.0 cable that comes with the phone, the phone charges but Ubuntu doesn't recognise it. I've tried all my ports but still no luck. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Does your PC/laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 have USB 3.0 ports?

Comment: It has one, but it doesn't matter which port I'm in, still no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you are able to do more than just charging with the USB 3 cable ? I have seen cable that can only do the charging but being USB 2.

Comment: Yes, i've used it in windows before just fine. It's the cable that came with the phone with the wide end:

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Hn-YpmEoL._SX425_.jpg